# Store things like Color, font, location in a dataset

Tags: vb.net, types, datatable, dataset

I know how to do this with MySettings as you can choose from many different types. However, I'm working with an untyped dataset, and I'm looking to store more custom types like color, font etc. An example of the class attributes I'm looking to store and retrieve:

```
 With MyNetMarquee       
        .MarqueeText = MarqueeEditor._GameBio
        .ScrollLeftToRight = ScrollingMarquee.Direction.Left
        .ScrollSpeed = 3
        .ForeColor = Color.Blue
        .ShadowColor = Color.Black
        .ShadowOffset = 5
        .StrokeSize = 4
        .StrokeColor = Color.Yellow
        .Font = New Drawing.Font("Centuriqua-Ultra", 40, FontStyle.Regular)
        .Location = New Point(100, 300)
    End With
```

I'm setting up the dataset via the Designer, so loathe to go into the designer code to experiment with code in there because I know this can seriously mess things up.

However, when I set up the specific datatable to store these in, only have the basic types (string, int32 etc). There is one called "system.object" - but this is a bit of a mystery to me. I have read the msndn artcile on it, but as ever, left me non the wiser.

Oh, and storing dataset via xml.

Apologies if this is overly generic, but not sure how else to ask it.

Comment: How does the dataset relate to the class?  Are you moving the data from the class to the DataSet to save it?

Comment: At design stage. Desired result will be xml>dataset>class. Edited via datagridview - so in parallel will be dataset>dgv>dataset>xml if that makes any sense at all!